# using a coffeescript node module in a nodejs project

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs

I am playing with a node module called `filings`

when I first used it, I did a `git clone` to get that project into a local directory, where I ran `npm install` and then `grunt` to build all of the coffeescripts into JS and get dependencies installed.

That works fine and I end up with a `/lib` directory with 13 files in it.

Now, i'm trying to use that module within a separate node project, so I installed it with `npm install filings` and a `node_modules/filings/lib` directory was created, but it only has 6 files in it, and a bunch of functionality is missing.

I've never installed a coffeescript node module into a regular node project before, is there something I can do to get it to properly build within my project?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the package on `npmjs.org`: If we clone a module from the repository, install it, and make package with `npm pack` then we get a very different contents of the package to install than the package manager on the site:

http://registry.npmjs.org/filings/-/filings-0.2.0.tgz

Answer (score 1):

## coffee-script require (generally spoken)

you can require coffee-script files from a javascript-file if you use `coffee-script/register` before.

therefore you need to install coffee-script locally:

```
$ npm install coffee-script --save
```

and use it in your code:

```
require('coffee-script/register');
require('youre-coffee-script-module');
```

## using the filings-module

**basic setup of filings**

the module itself has its main-script set to [./lib/filings.js](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/filings/blob/master/package.json#L11)

the lib-folder is compiled by the [grunt-task publish](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/filings/blob/master/Gruntfile.coffee#L39)

the publish-Task itself is triggered via the [prepublish-script](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/filings/blob/master/package.json#L33). so anytime the package-auther publishes his package via `npm publish` the lib-sources are build, an *afterwards* the compiled package is published.

in the [.npmignore](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/filings/blob/master/.npmignore) file all the source and testfiles are ignore, and therefore *not* published to npm!

**how to fix your problem**

i just see 2 more or less clean possibilities:

1. open an issue, and ask the package-auther to publish a new version to npm
2. create a fork, and use the fork

a) fork the repo

b1) add a `postinstall`-Property which runs the grunt-default-task `grunt`:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "grunt"
}
```

or b2) create a index.js file where you require the coffee-sources like i pointed out above

c) install the package from your repo: `npm install git+ssh://git@github.com:YOURGITHUBUSERNAME/filings.git`

d) maybe create a pull-request if you do version b2